# C#- Adding static IP without disturbing existing adapter configuration

Tags: c#, wmi

My question is kind of unique. I use the System.Management.dll in c# to do Adapter configurations. I'm successful in doing that, but I want to add Static IP without disturbing exisitng IP config of network adapter. If there is already an IP and subnet mask we should not disturb that by adding our new IP and mask. How can i do that in c#. Is system.management is the only API for Network adapters.

Comment: Can a network adapter have 2 IP addresses?

Comment: ya two static IP addressess.

Comment: You could just do this by calling `netsh` via `Process.Start`, ie: `netsh interface ipv4 add address "Connection Name" ip.for.iterface.xxx ip.for.dns.xxx`

Comment: @stuartd Interfaces can have many IP's, not just 2. Some servers have 10 or more for a single interface.

Comment: Correction to my first comment, the second IP is the subnet mask, not the DNS.